# Side loading powerpoint add-in with manifest.xml file on mac

Tags: macos, office-js, office-addins, sideloading, powerpoint-web-addins

I am working on a mac and have built an add-in for ms powerpoint. Office 365 family

App is deployed on azure.

Everything worked when i sideloaded using npm start and node server / localhost but I am now trying to sideload the add-in just using the manifest file and the source on azure.

MS Office documentation say to place the manifest into /Users//Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Powerpoint/Data/Documents/wef

I have done this but it is not showing in powerpoint add-ins.

Documentation also states that I should be able to 'upload add-in' via the add-in area, but this option isn't available in the add-in centre.

I tried putting the manifest file in /Users//Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Powerpoint/Data/Documents/wef
and expected to see the add-in available in powerpoint, but it is not

Answer (score 0):

Sideloaded add-ins will not show up in the `My Add-ins` dialog box. They are only visible within the drop-down menu (small down-arrow to the right of `My Add-ins` on the `Insert` tab). Sideloaded add-ins are listed under the `Developer Add-ins` heading in this menu.

See [Sideload Office Add-ins on Mac for testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/sideload-an-office-add-in-on-mac) for more information.

Comment: Have performed all the guidance multiple times per ms documentation and it is not showing in the developers add-ins. 

I am not looking to run this locally with a node server, but test just using the manifest reaching out to my hosted server.

Any other ways to install it?

Comment: What PowerPoint version do you use?